# How to abstract over two similar functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dry, abstraction

I have the following data definition about a football game:

```
Game = namedtuple('Game', ['Date', 'Home', 'Away', 'HomeShots', 'AwayShots',
                           'HomeBT', 'AwayBT', 'HomeCrosses', 'AwayCrosses',
                           'HomeCorners', 'AwayCorners', 'HomeGoals',
                           'AwayGoals', 'HomeXG', 'AwayXG'])
```

Here are some exmaples:

```
[Game(Date=datetime.date(2018, 10, 21), Home='Everton', Away='Crystal Palace', HomeShots='21', AwayShots='6', HomeBT='22', AwayBT='13', HomeCrosses='21', AwayCrosses='14', HomeCorners='10', AwayCorners='5', HomeGoals='2', AwayGoals='0', HomeXG='1.93', AwayXG='1.5'),
 Game(Date=datetime.date(2019, 2, 27), Home='Man City', Away='West Ham', HomeShots='20', AwayShots='2', HomeBT='51', AwayBT='6', HomeCrosses='34', AwayCrosses='5', HomeCorners='12', AwayCorners='2', HomeGoals='1', AwayGoals='0', HomeXG='3.68', AwayXG='0.4'),
 Game(Date=datetime.date(2019, 2, 9), Home='Fulham', Away='Man Utd', HomeShots='12', AwayShots='15', HomeBT='19', AwayBT='38', HomeCrosses='20', AwayCrosses='12', HomeCorners='5', AwayCorners='4', HomeGoals='0', AwayGoals='3', HomeXG='2.19', AwayXG='2.13'),
 Game(Date=datetime.date(2019, 3, 9), Home='Southampton', Away='Tottenham', HomeShots='12', AwayShots='15', HomeBT='13', AwayBT='17', HomeCrosses='15', AwayCrosses='15', HomeCorners='1', AwayCorners='10', HomeGoals='2', AwayGoals='1', HomeXG='2.08', AwayXG='1.27'),
 Game(Date=datetime.date(2018, 9, 22), Home='Man Utd', Away='Wolverhampton', HomeShots='16', AwayShots='11', HomeBT='17', AwayBT='17', HomeCrosses='26', AwayCrosses='13', HomeCorners='5', AwayCorners='4', HomeGoals='1', AwayGoals='1', HomeXG='0.62', AwayXG='1.12')]
```

And two almost identical functions calculating home and away statistics for a given team.

```
def calculate_home_stats(team, games):
    """
    Calculates home stats for the given team.
    """
    home_stats = defaultdict(float)

    home_stats['HomeShotsFor'] = sum(int(game.HomeShots) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeShotsAgainst'] = sum(int(game.AwayShots) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeBoxTouchesFor'] = sum(int(game.HomeBT) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeBoxTouchesAgainst'] = sum(int(game.AwayBT) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeCrossesFor'] = sum(int(game.HomeCrosses) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeCrossesAgainst'] = sum(int(game.AwayCrosses) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeCornersFor'] = sum(int(game.HomeCorners) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeCornersAgainst'] = sum(int(game.AwayCorners) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeGoalsFor'] = sum(int(game.HomeGoals) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeGoalsAgainst'] = sum(int(game.AwayGoals) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeXGoalsFor'] = sum(float(game.HomeXG) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeXGoalsAgainst'] = sum(float(game.AwayXG) for game in games if game.Home == team)
    home_stats['HomeGames'] = sum(1 for game in games if game.Home == team)

    return home_stats


def calculate_away_stats(team, games):
    """
    Calculates away stats for the given team.
    """
    away_stats = defaultdict(float)

    away_stats['AwayShotsFor'] = sum(int(game.AwayShots) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayShotsAgainst'] = sum(int(game.HomeShots) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayBoxTouchesFor'] = sum(int(game.AwayBT) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayBoxTouchesAgainst'] = sum(int(game.HomeBT) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayCrossesFor'] = sum(int(game.AwayCrosses) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayCrossesAgainst'] = sum(int(game.HomeCrosses) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayCornersFor'] = sum(int(game.AwayCorners) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayCornersAgainst'] = sum(int(game.HomeCorners) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayGoalsFor'] = sum(int(game.AwayGoals) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayGoalsAgainst'] = sum(int(game.HomeGoals) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayXGoalsFor'] = sum(float(game.AwayXG) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayXGoalsAgainst'] = sum(float(game.HomeXG) for game in games if game.Away == team)
    away_stats['AwayGames'] = sum(1 for game in games if game.Away == team)

    return away_stats
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to abstract over these two functions and merge them into one without creating a wall of if/else statements to determine whether the team plays at home or away from home and which fields should be counted.

Comment: I think the problem comes from your data structure. It's probably a good idea to design it so  this kind of abstraction becomes trivial. For example, playing away/home doesn't have any impact on the rest of the data (goals/shots/etc.)

Comment: So could you provide an alternative data definition which will help to make the required abstraction?

Comment: Sure, I'll have to make this in a regular answer tho, that's a bit long for a comment.

Comment: Organize your data so accessing home and away stats is more uniform. For example, have nested `game.HomeStats` and `game.AwayStats` data structures that store home and away stats in the same format instead of using two sets of separate attributes.

Comment: Looking forward to see it!

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica Is it such a good deal to change the data definition and rewrite all the functions relying on this data definition just for the sake of making a little abstraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having cleaner data structure allow for writing simpler code.
In that case, your data already contains duplication 
(eg, you have both `HomeShots` and `AwayShots`).

There are many possible answers to how you could structure data here.
I'll just go over a solution that doesn't change too much from 
your original structure.

```py
Statistics = namedtuple('Statistics', ['shots', 'BT', 'crosses', 'corners', 'goals', 'XG'])
Game = namedtuple('Game', ['home', 'away', 'date', 'home_stats', 'away_stats'])
```

You could use this like this (I haven't included all stats here, just a few to give an example):

```py
def calculate_stats(games, team_name, home_stats_only=False, away_stats_only=False):

    home_stats = [g.home_stats._asdict() for g in games if g.home == team_name]
    away_stats = [g.away_stats._asdict() for g in games if g.away == team_name]

    if away_stats_only:
        input_stats = away_stats
    elif home_stats_only:
        input_stats = home_stats
    else:
        input_stats = home_stats + away_stats

    def sum_on_field(field_name):
        return sum(stats[field_name] for stats in input_stats)

    return {f:sum_on_field(f) for f in Statistics._fields}
```

Which can then be used to get both away/home stats:

```py
example_game_1 = Game(
    home='Burnley', 
    away='Arsenal',
    date=datetime.now(),
    home_stats=Statistics(shots=12, BT=26, crosses=21, corners=4, goals=1, XG=1.73),
    away_stats=Statistics(shots=17, BT=26, crosses=22, corners=5, goals=3, XG=2.87),
)

example_game_2 = Game(
    home='Arsenal',
    away='Pessac',
    date=datetime.now(),
    home_stats=Statistics(shots=1, BT=1, crosses=1, corners=1, goals=1, XG=1),
    away_stats=Statistics(shots=2, BT=2, crosses=2, corners=2, goals=2, XG=2),
)

print(calculate_stats([example_game_1, example_game_2], 'Arsenal'))
print(calculate_stats([example_game_1, example_game_2], 'Arsenal', home_stats_only=True))
print(calculate_stats([example_game_1, example_game_2], 'Arsenal', away_stats_only=True))
```

Which prints:

```py
{'shots': 18, 'BT': 27, 'crosses': 23, 'corners': 6, 'goals': 4, 'XG': 3.87}
{'shots': 1, 'BT': 1, 'crosses': 1, 'corners': 1, 'goals': 1, 'XG': 1}
{'shots': 17, 'BT': 26, 'crosses': 22, 'corners': 5, 'goals': 3, 'XG': 2.87}
```

When dealing with this kind of data, it's usually a good idea to use specialised tools like, for example, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html). It could also be very convenient to use interactive tools, like [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the home and away stats are for the two different teams in a game, not for two separate matches.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense indeed.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica **this!** Given a regular championship for 20 teams, every team has 19 home and 19 away games and my functions calculate summary for them. There is no such a thing as `Match` in my program.

Comment: I was staring at your code trying to figure out what's happening :) Seems like you get it as a summary for a knock-out tournament rather than a regular championship.

Comment: @cglacet I have added some more examples into the code to make it clearer.

Comment: I updated the answer, that doesn't change the idea too much, but this time it makes sense in terms of footbal (I guess)

Comment: It seems like you are calculating stats for home and away teams overall, not for every team in particular. For example, when I call `calculate_home_stats('Arsenal', GAMES)` I get stats for **Arsenal** when they play at home, whereas your function seem to get overall home stats for all the teams combined. **Update** Apparently you have made an Edit when I was writing this.

Comment: On the other hand that's still true, but easy to modify.

Comment: You forgot to change the condition `if g.home == team_name` to `g.away` in the away case.

Comment: Also your code produces overall stats with no divison on home_stats and away_stats, which is the crux of the problem.

Comment: The output for home_stats should be like this: `{'HomeShotsFor': 242,
 'HomeShotsAgainst': 201,
 'HomeBoxTouchesFor': 517,
 'HomeBoxTouchesAgainst': 312,
 'HomeCrossesFor': 362,
 'HomeCrossesAgainst': 260,
 'HomeCornersFor': 125,
 'HomeCornersAgainst': 84,
 'HomeGoalsFor': 42,
 'HomeGoalsAgainst': 16,
 'HomeXGoalsFor': 37.67,
 'HomeXGoalsAgainst': 24.77,
 'HomeGames': 19}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215546/discussion-between-cglacet-and-konstantin-kostanzhoglo).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using a named tuple but a simple tuple with a dictionary, for example:

```
game=(datetime.date(2019, 5, 12), 'Burnley', 'Arsenal', '12', '17', '26', '26', '21', '22', '4', '5', '1', '3', '1.73', '2.87')
```

And a mapping dictionary:

```
numtostr={0: 'Date', 1: 'Home', 2: 'Away', 3: 'HomeShots', 4: 'AwayShots', 5: 'HomeBT', 6: 'AwayBT', 7: 'HomeCrosses', 8: 'AwayCrosses', 9: 'HomeCorners', 10: 'AwayCorners', 11: 'HomeGoals', 12: 'AwayGoals', 13: 'HomeXG'}
strtonum={'Date': 0, 'Home': 1, 'Away': 2, 'HomeShots': 3, 'AwayShots': 4, 'HomeBT': 5, 'AwayBT': 6, 'HomeCrosses': 7, 'AwayCrosses': 8, 'HomeCorners': 9, 'AwayCorners': 10, 'HomeGoals': 11, 'AwayGoals': 12, 'HomeXG': 13}
```

Make the mapping dictionaries for homestats and awaystats ({0: 'HomeShotsFor', 1: 'HomeShotsAgainst' etc} for home_stats). To explain how mapping dictionaries work, for example, if you want to get the HomeCrosses of a game, you can have

```
game[7]
```

or

```
game[strtonum['HomeCrosses']]
```

Then the functions:

```
def calculate_home_stats(team, games):
    home_stats=[0]*13
    for game in games:
        if game[1]=team:
            for index in range(12):
                home_stats[index]+=game[index+3] #because you just put the sum of everything except date, home, and away which are the first 3 indices. see how this cleans everything up?
            home_stats[12]+=1

def calculate_away_stats(team, games):
    away_stats=[0]*13
    for game in games:
        if game[2]=team:
            for index in range(12):
                away_stats[index]+=game[index+3]
            away_stats[12]+=1
```

If you really want to merge both functions into one you can do this:

```
def calculate_stats(team, games, homeaway):
    stats=[0]*13
    for game in games:
        if game[{'Home': 1, 'Away': 2}[homeaway]]=team:
            for index in range(12):
                stats[index]+=game[index+3]
            stats[12]+=1
```

As with my function the only thing you have to change is the index to check for home or away, instead of the redundant if else statements which require a lot of change.

Comment: To be honest not sure what is changes. We still have two almost identical functions which seem much less readable. Also it is not clear what's wrong with using `namedtuple`.

Comment: I edited the answer to better answer the question. I made the function less verbose so it is more easily changed and thus allow both functions to be merged without changing all the if else statement. I didn't use namedtuple because it means I cannot really do stats[index]+=game[index+3] with them, which constitutes all the if else statements we desperately don't want.